# nested iframe contentWindow is always null

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i am using Vue to make an app, i have a nested `iframe` in that app that loads content from AWS through a link and i have a message that needs to be sent to that iframe so i have a `ref` set on the iframe and using `this.$refs.frameRef.contentWindow.postMessage(...)` to send that message, but the console always shows an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
```

when i try to download that content to the local project to test things out its working perfectly but the problem here is when the content is deployed.

do anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

**Calling iframe too early**

I guess you are trying to call iframe window before it is fully loaded.

Try to call your *postMessage* after iframe's onload event.

```
var youriframe = document.getElementById('ifameid');

youriframe.onload = function() {
   youriframe.contentWindow.postMessage(...)
}
```

**Or possibly check if your iframe is not sandboxed**

Then you have to add **allow-same-origin**.

Comment: Thank you the `onload` was helpful but i figured out the problem, i was missing the target domain when calling the the `postMessage`, i was doing `postMessage('msg')` not `postMessage('msg', '*')`